# PHP Check the file is opend before rename

Tags: php

I have cleanup script, which move the XLS files from one place to another. for this file  moving process, I have used the rename function. This script is working fine. but when the XLS file is open, when I try to move that xls, I am getting error which simply say Can not rename sample.xls. But I would like to add the functionality like, Check the XLS is open before initiate rename function.

I believe this is function call `flock` but this is applicable for TXT file alone.

How to check XLS file is opened before call the rename function.

Comment: Instead of checking whether it's open, consider just catching the error if it goes wrong: `if (!rename(.., ..)) { }`

Comment: I don't think `flock` is only for .txt files.. have you tried it?

Comment: Have you considered to change the behaviour so that the files are copied to the new location instead of moved, and then a cronjob will try to clear the old useless files. If they are opened or not deletable, the cronjob will try to delete the file during next execution. It is a common approach.

Comment: You should try to use [**`flock`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) however depending on how other applications are reading it may have no effect.

Comment: @Oli window,    FDL: flock, i dont tried. but i assume

Comment: @Bharanikumar don't assume read the manual if you're not sure ;) it says it works but depends on how the files are being used.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt  there is " n " number reasons available for failure.as per your sample. the custom error message will display when ever rename gets failed. but i need error reason also.

Comment: For flock  first argument is resource $handle but in my script i dont have fopen function @ all

Comment: @Eggplant still problem when delete if the file is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple thing you could try is to use **[`flock`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)** to acquire a Exclusive Lock on the file and if it fails you will know the file is being used:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('c:/your_file.xlsx', 'r+');
if(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX))
{
    echo 'File is being used...';
    exit(-1);
}
else
{
    fclose($fp);
    // rename(...);
}
```

An alternative would be to check the existence of the locking file excel usually creates when a file is being used:

```
<?php
$file = 'c:/testfile.xlsx';
$lock = 'c:/~$testfile.xlsx';
if (file_exists($lock))
{
    echo "Excel $file is locked.";
}
else
{
    echo "Excel $file is free.";
}
```

The hidden file is usually name with the prefix `~$` as for old excel files I believe 2003 and older the lock files are saved on the temp folder with a random name like `~DF7B32A4D388B5854C.TMP` so it would be pretty hard to find out.

Comment: i just tried this just mins ago. i opened the XLS and ran this code. but my rename function getting execute.

Comment: @Bharanikumar and it fails or works ? PHP is not the best solution for this case specially for windows OS, C# or c++ would be more suitable IMHO.

Comment: ho my god.then what is the purpose of this flock.

Comment: @Bharanikumar so did it still allowed you to rename the file or returned false when you tried rename ?

Comment: @Bharanikumar then how about verifying for the hidden file excel generates when the file is being read/open ?

Comment: your first example code working now. i dont know. why that one not worked on that day. But i am getting WARNING message like " permission denied .... "

Comment: @Bharanikumar Excel does not lock the files when reading it, it replicates the file into a temp file so flock will not work, like I have said on your messages comments flock will only work if the applications reading a file actually use similar approach where excel does not. So if u want to make sure no one is read the file, you need to check it against the temporary files.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`flock()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php).  This puts a flag on the file so that other scripts are informed that the file is in use.  The flag is turned off either intentionally using `fclose` or implicitly by the end of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Use file lock like:

```
flock($file,LOCK_EX);
```

see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_flock.asp)